# Something about distributed tensorflow with sync update

Tags: tensorflow, synchronization, distribute

I'm trying to use distributed tensorflow with sync update. However, the workers seem to stop after step 1, then the session seems can't run the update operation. Just the line below :

```
acc_value, cost_value, _ = sess.run([acc, cost, train_op],
                                                {input_: x_minibatch, label_: y_minibatch})
```

And the output of my program is shown as below:
[it just stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUJhA.png)

I'm quite sure that there are something wrong about the sync setting of my code.
And here is all of my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import h5py
import numpy as np
import threading
import time
import pickle
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from model import le_net


def get_data(task_index, batch_size, lock_):
    with lock_:
        with h5py.File('data_util/mnist.h5') as f:
            x_train = f['x_train'].value.astype(np.float32)
            y_train = f['y_train'].value
            x_test = f['x_test'].value.astype(np.float32)
            y_test = f['y_test'].value
    interval_len = 60000//6
    task_x = x_train[interval_len*task_index: interval_len*(task_index+1)]
    task_y = y_train[interval_len*task_index: interval_len*(task_index+1)]
    batch_num = task_x.shape[0]//batch_size
    x_mini_batch = [task_x[batch_size*i: batch_size*(i+1)] for i in range(batch_num)]
    y_mini_batch = [task_y[batch_size*i: batch_size*(i+1)] for i in range(batch_num)]
    return x_mini_batch, y_mini_batch, x_test, y_test, batch_num


def work(devices, job_name, task_index, lock_, worker_num):
    config = tf.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(devices)
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name=job_name, task_index=task_index, config=config)
    if job_name == 'ps':
        server.join()
    else:
        device = '/job:worker/task:' + str(task_index)
        is_chief = (task_index == 0)
        # is_chief = True
        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device=device, cluster=cluster)):
            input_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28, 28, 3], 'input_name')
            label_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], 'label_data')
            output_ = le_net(input_, 10, 'worker')
            acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(output_, 1), tf.argmax(label_, 1)), tf.float32), name='acc')
            cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=label_, logits=output_), name='cost')
            global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()
            optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0002)
            rep_op = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(
                optimizer,
                replicas_to_aggregate=worker_num,
                total_num_replicas=worker_num
            )
            train_op = rep_op.minimize(cost, global_step=global_step)
        hooks = [tf.train.StopAtStepHook(num_steps=804), rep_op.make_session_run_hook(is_chief, 0)]
        with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                               # checkpoint_dir='checkpoint',
                                               hooks=hooks,
                                               # save_checkpoint_secs=600,
                                               config=config,
                                               is_chief=True) as sess:
            print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
            print('start task_index:%d' % task_index)
            x_data, y_data, x_test, y_test, batch_num = get_data(task_index, 128, lock_)
            train_acc = []
            train_cost = []
            val_acc = []
            val_cost = []
            total_step = 0
            while not sess.should_stop():
                x_minibatch = x_data[total_step % batch_num]
                y_minibatch = y_data[total_step % batch_num]
                acc_value, cost_value, _ = sess.run([acc, cost, train_op],
                                                    {input_: x_minibatch, label_: y_minibatch})
                train_acc.append((total_step, acc_value))
                train_cost.append((total_step, cost_value))
                print('task_index %d, step %d, train_acc %4f, train_cost %4f' %
                      (task_index, total_step, acc_value, cost_value))
                if total_step % 100 == 0:
                    val_acc_value, val_cost_value = sess.run([acc, cost],
                                                             {input_: x_test[:256], label_: y_test[:256]})
                    val_acc.append((total_step, val_acc_value))
                    val_cost.append((total_step, val_cost_value))
                    print('task_index %d, step %d, train_acc %4f, train_cost %4f, val_acc %4f, val_cost %4f' %
                          (task_index, total_step, acc_value, cost_value, val_acc_value, val_cost_value))
                total_step += 1
                if task_index == 0 and total_step == 200:
                    current_time = int(time.time())
                    with open('result/task_index-%d-worker_num-%d-time-%d-train-acc.pkl' % (task_index, worker_num, current_time), 'wb') as f:
                        pickle.dump(train_acc, f)
                    with open('result/task_index-%d-worker_num-%d-time-%d-train-lost.pkl' % (task_index, worker_num, current_time), 'wb') as f:
                        pickle.dump(train_cost, f)
                    with open('result/task_index-%d-worker_num-%d-time-%d-val-acc.pkl' % (task_index, worker_num, current_time), 'wb') as f:
                        pickle.dump(val_acc, f)
                    with open('result/task_index-%d-worker_num-%d-time-%d-val-lost.pkl' % (task_index, worker_num, current_time), 'wb') as f:
                        pickle.dump(val_cost, f)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = threading.Lock()
    devices_ = {
        'ps': ['10.13.75.116:5000', '10.13.75.116:5001'],
        'worker': ['10.13.75.116:5002', '10.13.75.116:5003', '10.13.75.116:5004', '10.13.75.116:5005']
    }
    task = [('ps', 0), ('ps', 1), ('worker', 0), ('worker', 1), ('worker', 2), ('worker', 3)]
    worker_num = 4        
    ps = [threading.Thread(target=work, args=(devices_, i, j, lock, worker_num)) for i, j in task]
    [p.start() for p in ps]
    [p.join() for p in ps[2:]]
```